# Getting Mojolicious to work on OpenShift

Tags: perl, openshift, mojolicious

Is there a way to make perl Mojolicious::Lite to work on OpenShift without jumping through hoops? This is typically what needs to be done: [Mojolicious_Lite_on_OpenShift](https://github.com/Nkawu/Mojolicious_Lite_on_OpenShift)

Support for perl & Mojolicious on OpenShift has improved a lot over the last few years to the point that it appears to be a simple click-and-install process. However out of the box, I cannot get Mojolicious to find ANY embedded templates, and using external templates, it will only find the '/' route's template.

I'm using a very simple Mojo script:

```
use Mojolicious::Lite;

get '/' => 'index';

get '/foo' => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->render(template => 'foo')
};

app->start;
```

The first route '...rhcloud.com/' works, displaying ./templates/index.html.ep

However '...rhcloud.com/foo' fails, dumping out app-root/logs/perl.log:

[Wed Apr 01 14:02:06 2015] [error] [client 127.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /var/lib/openshift/551b352b4382ec9a2800000a/app-root/runtime/repo/foo

In the past I was able to make Mojo work using [Mojolicious::Lite on OpenShift](https://github.com/degtyarev-dm/mojolicious-lite-openshift), but that doesn't appear to work any more.

Has anyone been able to get this to work recently???

A simple way to replicate this issue:

```
use Mojolicious::Lite;

get '/' => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->render(template => 'index')
};

app->start;

__DATA__

@@ index.html.ep
INDEX
```

You should get an error that index.html.ep could not be found.

***Please note that this question is specific to Mojolicious in the OpenShift environment!***

Comment: Do you have your whole example project in a github repo that we can look at or try ourselves? (including your sample template?)

Comment: @corey112358 - I added more info to the original post, including self-contained code that can be pasted to index.pl.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the part where you run the index.pl file as a psgi application, try using the answer to this question ([Can openshift/rhcloud variables be used in an .htaccess file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29402464/can-openshift-rhcloud-variables-be-used-in-an-htaccess-file)) to setup your .htaccess file so that it will route the /foo url to your index.pl so it can control the routes

Comment: Actually, I am doing that as mentioned in the link in the original post: https://github.com/Nkawu/Mojolicious_Lite_on_OpenShift.  I'm guessing this is because we're forced to use Apache? Mojo just seems to works a lot easier on Heroku, especially since you're allowed to use different web servers.